# How to get all the RelativeLayout parametres from a View

Tags: android, android-view

I have a ImageView in my relative layout.
How can I get all the parametres of this ImageView: not the x and y but I need all the parametres from this view: like CenterHorizontal = true etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `int[] RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.getRules()` defined here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#getRules().

Take the rules, parse it and get the value.

Answer (score 7):

To get the **rules** (i.e parameter) use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.
 So you need to get the `LayoutParams` from the `View`.

To get all **rules**, use `getRules()` in `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

The array of point to [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) constant by index.

For example:

- rule `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT` contain ID of the View align left
- rule `RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL` contain `RelativeLayout.TRUE` if it is set.

Comment: Must be the selected answer as it states exactly what the OP had asked.